# Jakarta EE 10 REST API returns 404 not found error

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

MyApplication.java

```
package service;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/app")
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();
    
    public MyApplication(){
        singletons.add(new HelloResource());
    }
    
    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

HelloResource.java

```
package service;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getHello() {
        return "HELLO";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Resteasy-examples</groupId>
  <artifactId>Resteasy-examples</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>17</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I go to this address http://localhost:8080/Resteasy-examples/app/hello and

## HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

---

**Type** Status Report

**Message** The requested resource [/Resteasy-examples/app/hello] is not available

**Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

---

#### Apache Tomcat/9.0.73

when i do the same example for resteasy-jaxrs 3.1.3.final it works but that doesn't work.

Comment: HTTP 404 means your URL isn't correct.  Check each contribution carefully.  Ask Tomcat what endpoints it exposes.

Comment: You are using Tomcat 9. That expects to use the Servlet 4.0 specification (required by the Java EE 8 platform). However, your POM is using the Jakarta EE 10 artifact, so you have downloaded the Servlet 6.0 specification. For this you need to be using Tomcat 10.1.x. See the [Apache Tomcat Versions](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) guide. Upgrade your Tomcat. (I'm not claiming this will fix your 404 error, though.)

Comment: One other thing: Do you actually want to use the RESTEasy implementation of JAX-RS (given the title of your project)? I don't see that in your POM.

Comment: Apart from the Jakarta/Tomcat9 issue, you don't even have a JAX-RS _implementation_. Tomcat is not an EE server. It will not have an implementation. So you need to add one.

Comment: Also, whet does this even mean? _"when i do the same example for resteasy-jaxrs 3.1.3.final it works but that doesn't work."_